# How to use samepage environment in the middle of a table?

Tags: tables, page-breaking

I use the following code to generate a document:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}  
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{datenumber}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%Column width for tables
\def \firstColumnWidth {3.5cm}
\def \secondColumnWidth {12.5cm}

%This is the headline
\newcommand{\headline}[1] {
\section*{#1}
\vspace{-1.75em}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
\vspace{-1.75em}
}

\begin{document}

\headline{Test A}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{\firstColumnWidth}p{\secondColumnWidth}}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.75}2015}\\
Foo & \blindtext\\
Bar & \blindtext\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.75}2014}\\
Foo & \blindtext\\
Bar & \blindtext\\
\end{tabularx}

\headline{Test B}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{\firstColumnWidth}p{\secondColumnWidth}}
Foo & \blindtext\\
Bar & \blindtext\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Now, I want to make sure that the headline and the first row of a table is always on the same page. I tried to do that with `\begin{samepage}` and `\end{samepage}`, but the problem is that `\end{samepage}` cannot be in the middle of the table. What other options do I have?

Comment: ltablex somewhat confusingly turns tabularx into longtable so (a) you should not have `\noindent` before it and (b) you can use longtable commands such as `\endfirsthead` to control which lines stay together at the start

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The problem is that the \headline is not part of the table and so I imho can't use the \endfirsthead command.

Comment: latex section heading prevent page breaks after them but you have defeated that by `\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}` that should never be after the section heading, if you want an underlined heading that should be in the specification of the heading style, not in the document.

Comment: You can manually tweak it as `\usepackage{needspace}` and `\needspace{10\baselineskip}\headline{Test B}`

Answer (score 5):

You have no `X` columns so `tabularx` is doing nothing useful here. You can just use `longtable` and prevent page breaks with `\\*` Unfortunately `longtable` always allows a break at a `\hline` but it is simple to define a variant that doesn't.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter
\def\nbhline{%no break hline
\noalign{%
  \global\let\tmp\@lowpenalty
  \gdef\@lowpenalty{-10000 }}%
\hline
\noalign{\global\let\@lowpenalty\tmp}}

\makeatother

\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
%Column width for tables
\def \firstColumnWidth {3.5cm}
\def \secondColumnWidth {12.5cm}

%This is the headline
\newcommand\headline[1]{%
\noalign{\medskip}%
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\large\bfseries#1}\\*\nbhline
\noalign{\nobreak\smallskip}}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{\firstColumnWidth}p{\secondColumnWidth}}
\headline{Test A}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.75}2015}\\
Foo & \blindtext\\
Bar & \blindtext\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.75}2014}\\
Foo & \blindtext\\
Bar & \blindtext\\
\headline{Test B}
Foo & \blindtext\\
Bar & \blindtext\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution. I make \headline part of tabularx. There is no need to split tabular

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}  
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{datenumber}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%Column width for tables
\def \firstColumnWidth {3.5cm}
\def \secondColumnWidth {12.5cm}

%This is the headline
\newcommand{\headline}[1] {%
\multicolumn{2}{@{}p{\textwidth}}{\Large\bfseries #1\par
\vspace{-.75em}
\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}}\\*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{\firstColumnWidth}p{\secondColumnWidth}}
\headline{Test A}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.75}2015}\\
Foo & \blindtext\\
Bar & \blindtext\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.75}2014}\\
Foo & \blindtext\\
Bar & \blindtext\\
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{\firstColumnWidth}p{\secondColumnWidth}}
\headline{Test B}
Foo & \blindtext\\
Bar & \blindtext\\
\end{tabularx}



\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{\firstColumnWidth}p{\secondColumnWidth}}
\headline{Test A}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.75}2015}\\
Foo & \blindtext\\
Bar & \blindtext\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.75}2014}\\
Foo & \blindtext\\
Bar & \blindtext\\
\headline{Test B}
Bar & \blindtext\\
Bar & \blindtext\\
Foo & \blindtext\\
Bar & \blindtext\\
Bar & \blindtext\\
Bar & \blindtext\\
Bar & \blindtext\\
Bar & \blindtext\\
\headline{Test C}
Foo & \blindtext\\
Bar & \blindtext\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```