# Is there an equivalent for \needspace in the longtable environment?

Tags: spacing, longtable

I have a long table with rows that I would like to keep on the same page. Is there an equivalent to \needspace that will work in a longtable environment?

Comment: the longtable package documentation discusses page breaking, you should be able to use `\\*` in most cases

Comment: I get a page break after //*

Comment: do you use `\hline` ? (in any case you should provide an example document.

Comment: I use both hline and cline.

Comment: the easiest thing to do is put a \pagebreak earlier in the table at the point that you do want the break

Comment: I don't want a page break if the material will fir on the current page. That's why I tried \needspace.

Comment: ah found it, see the no break \hline here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231461/1090