# How to make \hhline work with longtable's \\*

Tags: page-breaking, longtable, hhline

1. `longtable` provides `\\*` which can prevent the pagebreak, <del>and `longtable` redefines `\hline` to support this function</del>.
2. Then, `multirow` enhances `\cline` to support that function. 
   One can use package option "longtable" to load the enhancement, see `texdoc multirow`, sec. 3.6.
3. It seems that `\hhline` from `hhline` package does not work with `\\*`.

Is there a way to make `hhline` work with `\\*`? Maybe [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44800) can be a start point, but I am not sure.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[longtable]{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\textheight4\baselineskip
\pdfpageheight5\textheight

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{*{3}{|l}|}
    \hline
    A & B                 & C \\ \hline
    A & B                 & C \\ \hline
    A & B                 & C \\* \cline{2-3}
    A & \cellcolor{pink}B & C \\* \cline{2-3}
    A & B                 & C \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\newpage
\begin{longtable}{*{3}{|l}|}
    \hline
    A & B                 & C \\ \hline
    A & B                 & C \\ \hline
    A & B                 & C \\* \hhline{|~|-|-|}
    A & \cellcolor{pink}B & C \\* \hhline{|~|-|-|}
    A & B                 & C \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I need to use `\cellcolor` inside a `longtable` hence `\hhline` seems to be a must, by `texdoc colortbl`, sec. 10.

Comment: longtable `\\*` does not prevent page breaks at a following `\hline

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Then, does `multirow` actually make `\cline` working with `\\*`, as stated in its package doc?

Comment: I assume so, I don't really use multirow and never looked at its internals. I think I have an answer on this site showing how to have a non-breaking hline in longtable, I will see if I can find.....

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228990/how-to-use-samepage-environment-in-the-middle-of-a-table/231461#231461

Answer (score 1):

With `longtblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package, `\\*`, `\cline` and cell color work as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[height=3cm,paperheight=4cm,width=3cm,paperwidth=4cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\SetTblrTemplate{head,foot}{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}{*{3}{|l}|}
    \hline
    A & B                & C \\ \hline
    A & B                & C \\ \hline
    A & B                & C \\* \cline{2-3}
    A & \SetCell{pink} B & C \\* \cline{2-3}
    A & B                & C \\ \hline
\end{longtblr}
```

[image]